# Сreating a multi-level dictionary

Tags: python

I have many files with data organized like this:

```
20190920;100000;MGNT;3616
20190920;100000;RSTI;10128
20190920;100001;SIBN;4150.5
20190920;100001;SNGSP;3771.5
20190920;100002;MGNT;3617
20190920;100002;TATN;2966.8
20190920;100003;SNGSP;15086
20190920;100004;TATNP;1359.6
20190920;100005;SNGSP;75410
20190920;100005;AFLT;133672.4
20190920;100005;SNGSP;3771.5
```

I want to read them and create a dictionary.
Tickers like MGNT, TATN are its keys.
Its values are dictionaries like

```
{20190920 : value}
```

where value is list of digits:

```
[3616, 3617 .....] #they are the last digits in my data example.
```

So, this is something like

```
{'MGNT' : {20190920 : [3616, 3617, 3615]}}
```

this is what I do with no result

```
crude_base = {}
for item in datafiles: #loop throw files. 1 file contains data for 1 day
    # open file
    for line in file_object:    
        line = line.split(';')  
        date = line[0]
        time = line[1]
        ticker = line[2]
        price = line[3]
        #Now I want to append price in list inside crude_base[ticker][data]
```

How can I append price in list inside the dictionary?

Comment: It looks to me like the list you get from `line.split` should have a length of 4, but in your example, you set price to `line[2]`. Shouldn't it be `3`, or am I missing something?

Comment: thank you. I will correct now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want, assuming you don't care about saving the time.

```py
crude_base = {}
for item in datafiles:
    # open file
    for line in file_object:
        line = line.split(';')
        date = line[0]
        time = line[1]
        ticker = line[2]
        price = line[3]
        if ticker not in crude_base:
            crude_base[ticker] = {}
        if date not in crude_base[ticker]:
            crude_base[ticker][date] = [price]
        else:
            crude_base[ticker][date].append(price)
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the first `price` is added twice in you example, there should be an `else` in the penultimate line.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to check if the keys exist, something like what follows:

```
crude_base = {}
for item in datafiles: #loop throw files. 1 file contains data for 1 day
    # open file
    for line in file_object:    
        line = line.split(';')  
        date = line[0]
        time = line[1]
        ticker = line[2]
        price = line[3]
        if ticker not in crude_base:
            # Create the first level with a dictionary
            crude_base[ticker] = {date: [price]}
        else:
            # crude_base[ticker] exists and is a dictionary
            if date in crude_base[ticker]:
                # Date list already exists, just add the price to the list
                crude_base[ticker][date].append(price)
            else:
                # Create the dictionary entry for this date
                crude_base[ticker][date] = [price]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a defaultdict which will build a dictionary for you without you having to define the keys.

Using this you can define a dictionary nested within another dictionary, with the value of a list. When you use the crude_base[ticker][date] reference an empty list is automatically created (or whatever item you specify, for example you could specify a set or int, etc.).

The code then would look like;

```
from collections import defaultdict


crude_base = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

# 1. loop thought the files
for item in datafiles:

    # 2. open file
    for line in file_object: 

        # 3. Unpack into parts
        date, time, ticker, price = line.split(';')

        # 4. Append price in list inside crude_base[ticker][date]
        crude_base[ticker][date].append(price)
```